# Relationship 1-n multiple BACKPACK Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I use backpack 5 Pro on last laravel.

I would like to select several data, save them in the database and retrieve them.

I have two tables :

**products** - id, name

**articles** - id, title, products_id

In my model **Articles.php** :

```
public function produit()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Products', 'products_id', 'id');
}
```

In my controller **ArticlesCrudController.php** :

```
$this->crud->addField(
    [
        'label'     => "Products Links",
        'type'      => 'relationship',
        'name'      => 'produit', 
        'entity'    => 'produit', 
        'model'     => "App\Models\Products",
        'attribute' => 'product_name', 
        'allows_null' => true,
        'multiple'     => true, <--- WANT MULTIPLE SELECT
        'tab' => 'Products links',
        'options'   => (function ($query) {
                    return $query->orderBy('product_name', 'ASC')->get();
        }),
    ]
);
```

In my Database :

**products_id** contains : ["15","18"]

Everything works fine except in my results list. It only shows me one result (id : 15) instead of two or more... (15 and 18).

[image: list result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you can make such relation, you can store only one value within `product_id`.

Based on your structure, your Product can have multiple Articles, so create two lines (two records in DB) in your articles:

Consider this pseudo code:

```php
$article1 = [
   'id' => 1,
   'title' => 'Article 1',
   'product_id' => 15
];

$article2 = [
   'id' => 1,
   'title' => 'Article 1',
   'product_id' => 15
]
```

Now Product with ID of 15 has 2 articles (1 and 2).

If you want your Article to have multiple Products and vice-versa then create [Many to many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)